# import fbx files based on path from txt

Tags: python, scripting, import

Hello I have txt file with saved path to folder with fbx's to import.

How to force blender to reading the path from txt.
And use it to import fbx.

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys 
import os 

path = "D:/test/Path.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as f:
line = f.read().rstrip()
print(line)
```

I get this

D:\Frontals\model\All

And I want to use this location like path to import my fbx. from  D:\Frontals\model\All.

my script for import

```
folder = Path(r"D:\test\handle")
fbx_files = [f for f in folder.glob("**/*.fbx")]
for fbx_file in fbx_files:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=str(fbx_file))
```

Comment: `folder = Path(line)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate importFBX.py and put something like -

```
import bpy
import os
import sys

fbxFilePath = sys.argv[-2]
blendFilePath = sys.argv[-1]

# Import FBX
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = fbxFilePath )
bpy.context.object.scale = (0.01, 0.01, 0.01)

# Save blend file
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=blendFilePath)
```

Then call the separate python file to read all the fbx paths and call them from command line as an argument to the blender executable like -

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

# blender executable path
blenderPath 
 =r'"C:\ProgramFiles\BlenderFoundation\Blender\2.81\blender.exe" '



importfbxScript = r'\importFBX.py'

folder = Path(r"D:\test\handle")
fbx_files = [f for f in folder.glob("**/*.fbx")]
for fbx_file in fbx_files:
    fbxFilePath = os.path.join(folder, fbx_file)
    
    blenderFilePath = \\ .blend file path where you want to save the blend file

    cmd = blenderPath + " --background -P " \
                  + importfbxScript + " " + fbxFilePath \
                  + " " + blenderFilePath
                        
    p = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```